# T-SQL(MS SQL 2008), Executing procedure without 'EXEC' or 'EXECUTE' word

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec, execute

Is it OK to execute a stored procedure without 'EXEC' or 'EXECUTE' word in the beginning ?

Normally to execute stored procedure I do

```
EXEC DeleteProfile 'Joe Smith'
```

But, I've noticed that next command works as well:

```
DeleteProfile 'Joe Smith'
```

Why should I write 'EXEC' or 'EXECUTE' word?

Is it ok not to write it before stored procedure name to execute stored procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found in MSDN
"You do not have to specify the EXECUTE keyword when you execute stored procedures when the statement is the first one in a batch."

Get it. Sorry for question.

This wouldn't work without GO at the end of each statement:

```
DeleteProfile 'Joe Smith'
DeleteProfile 'Joe Smith'
DeleteProfile 'Joe Smith'
```

Comment: It's quite acceptable to ask a (reasonable) question and then answer it. I didn't know that the exec was at all optional, so you've taught me something today (+1 for that)

Comment: I did notice Exec was now optional in Sql server 2008+higher, but didn't know about the "when the statement is the first one in a batch" requirement which seems like a big "gotcha" that would have been confusing to debug one day. So I have also learned something useful :) Thanks!